# File upload Issue for External user outside the application - ASP.NET MVC Impersonation

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, iis-7, impersonation

I have a requirement where I want to create a survey form and user will have option to upload files. The website is an ASP.NET MVC application.

Those users have only access to the survey form and they don't have access to any other pages in the application. The file to be uploaded to the shared folder located in the same server where application hosted.

The access permission to the folder is only for a particular AD group. The external user who uploads the file is not part of that AD group.

```
     [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Upload()
    {
         string fileUniqueName = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
            {
                HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[i];
                string fileName = file.FileName;
                fileUniqueName = string.Format("{0}_{1}_{2}",
                Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.FileName),
                DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss_FFF"),
                Path.GetExtension(file.FileName));
                string tempFileUploadFolderPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TempFolderPath"];
                Directory.CreateDirectory(tempFileUploadFolderPath);
                string fileFullpath = Path.Combine(tempFileUploadFolderPath, fileUniqueName);
                file.SaveAs(fileFullpath);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
            return new JsonResult
            {
                Data = ""
            };
        }
        
        return new JsonResult
        {
            Data = fileUniqueName
        };
    }
```

I have below setting in web.config

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<identity impersonate="true" />
```

Can anyone please guide how to do the file upload functionality in this scenario? Can we do anything with impersonation?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done.

Just set the identity of application pool to be one of user in AD group so that application has permission to store survey in shared folder.

Comment: ..But while uploading, it runs with logged in users's identity and because of that permission is denied. How can I run the specific piece of file upload code in AppPool Identity ???

Comment: I answered this question in your newest thread, you can check it.